# google map intent not animate to current location in android app...?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, maps

I have an android application in which one place I want to call maps.google.com intent and display direction from source to destination.

But when I use this, I want maps animate to direction path automatically.

I use below for calling maps intent

`String saddr = "current location";
String daddr = "other location";`

`Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ saddr+ "&daddr="+ daddr));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);`

intent call properly and show me maps, and draw path as well but not animate to that place.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link out:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

In your:

```
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ saddr+ "&daddr="+ daddr)
```

try:

```
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ saddr+ "&daddr="+ daddr+"&z=10")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I already refer link given by you, but z(zoom) level not help me. I want to animate map to the path which draw by given Uri.parse.